# Pass series instead of integer to pandas offsets

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (df) with a date and a number.  I want to add the number to the date.  How do I add the df['additional_days'] series to the df['start_date'] series using pd.offsets()?  Is there a better way to do this?

> start_date    additional_days
>
> 2018-03-29    360
>
> 2018-07-31    0
>
> 2018-11-01    360
>
> 2016-11-03    720
>
> 2018-12-04    480

I get an error when I try

```
df['start_date'] + pd.offsets.Day(df['additional_days'])
```

Here is the error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
pandas/_libs/tslibs/offsets.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.offsets._BaseOffset._validate_n()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in wrapper(self)
    117         raise TypeError("cannot convert the series to "
--> 118                         "{0}".format(str(converter)))
    119 

TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-76-03920804db29> in <module>
----> 1 df_test['start_date'] + pd.offsets.Day(df_test['additional_days'])

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/tseries/offsets.py in __init__(self, n, normalize)
   2219     def __init__(self, n=1, normalize=False):
   2220         # TODO: do Tick classes with normalize=True make sense?
-> 2221         self.n = self._validate_n(n)
   2222         self.normalize = normalize
   2223 

pandas/_libs/tslibs/offsets.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.offsets._BaseOffset._validate_n()

TypeError: `n` argument must be an integer, got <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Comment: There may be other reasons, but I find that `pd.offsets` is typically best used when needing specific logic for adding a constant less well-defined time period. A day is very well-defined, so there is never any ambiguity as to what a Date + X days means. Conversely, something like `1 Month` is not well defined, so `pd.offsets.DateOffset` gives you the ability to define it with some useful logic according to the [relativedelta](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html) logic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `pd.to_timedelta`

```
import pandas as pd
#df['start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.start_date)

df['start_date'] + pd.to_timedelta(df.additional_days, unit='d')

#0   2019-03-24
#1   2018-07-31
#2   2019-10-27
#3   2018-10-24
#4   2020-03-28
#dtype: datetime64[ns]
```